# Convert CakePHP 1.2 to CakePHP 2.3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am working on project which was developed in CakePHP 1.3 by someone. I am confused there are some differences in different versions of cakephp i don't feel comfortable in ver 1.3. i want to change it to cakephp 2.3. is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible but will be a cumbersome task if you are migrating a large app.

You need to follow the [2.0 migration guide](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html), that will help you get your application working with version 2.0, then follow the minor version migration guides until your app is compliant and working with the latest version of CakePHP, which is 2.3 at the moment.

Comment: Matt- Thanx. This is a large app. but i need to do it compulsorily. I wish everything work fine after migration.

Comment: @SherazAli you may wish so but this will rarely happen. If it is a really big application be prepared to re-write a lot of stuff. 
I've personally "played this game" with a very large app and it was quite a hassle. But don't worry the mirgation console will solve a big part of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Sure! It can be done and to be honest, if you follow the migration guide then it won't be too complex. 
Yes it WILL be hard work and lengthy, but not complex.